# PHP MySql Update else Insert Error "Warning: mysql_result()"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to go threw my table nonbulkmdu and look into r10database to find if there is a duplicate, if there is it will update 4 fields if its not it will insert a new row. I keep getting the error

`Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in on line 19-23.`

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$username="";
$password="";
$database="";
$link = mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);


mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query="SELECT * FROM nonbulkmdu";

if ($result=mysql_query($query, $link)) {
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {
        $address=strtoupper(mysql_result($result,$i,"address"));
        $drops=mysql_result($result,$i,"drops");
        $city=mysql_result($result,$i,"city");
        $citycode=mysql_result($result,$i,"citycode");
        $feature_type=mysql_result($result,$i,"Feature_Type");

        $result = mysql_query("update r10_database
                               set drops=$drops, citycode=$citycode, city=$city, Feature_Type=$feature_type 
                               where address=$address;");  

        if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
            $result = mysql_query("insert into r10_database (address,
                                                             drops, 
                                                             city, 
                                                             citycode, 
                                                             Feature_Type) 
                                                     values ($address,
                                                             $drops,
                                                             $city,
                                                             $citycode,
                                                             $Feature_Type);");
        }
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Obligatory notice [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The formatting on your code is off.  Which line is the error on?

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool to mark code, not the `""` tool, which is for quoting plain text.

Comment: Change your `mysql_query()` call to `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` so you'll see the reason for the failure.

Comment: First this `if ($result=mysql_query($query, $link)) {` needs to be `==` // --- you're making an assignment while it should be a comparison.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not a comparison, it's assigning to `result` and testing whether it assigned `false`.

Comment: @Barmar Really? Well I won't argue with you on that. I guess there's another little something I didn't know. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm surprised. Haven't you seen `while ($row = fetch(...))`? It's the same idea -- doing an assignment and testing at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar To tell you the truth, I didn't know those 2 were the same. I'm going to read up on it to get myself more familiar with it. I've only been doing DB code for a month now, so I'm still a novice, but I do get by rather well with what I learned so far. (Notice I haven't been "asking" questions) ;-) thanks again for the added info.

Comment: It's not DB-specific, it's just PHP syntax, and it's just like C and Javascript. `if()` and `while()` both just test the expression in parentheses -- `if` does it once, `while` does it repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around the values in the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` call:

```
    $result = mysql_query("update r10_database
                           set drops='$drops', citycode='$citycode', city='$city', Feature_Type='$feature_type' 
                           where address='$address';");  

    if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
        $result = mysql_query("insert into r10_database (address,
                                                         drops, 
                                                         city, 
                                                         citycode, 
                                                         Feature_Type) 
                                                 values ('$address',
                                                         '$drops',
                                                         '$city',
                                                         '$citycode',
                                                         '$Feature_Type');")
```

BTW, if `address` has a unique key in the table, you can do both queries at once, using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).